# How to get the result of a future in a callback?

Tags: python, distributed, dask

The `add_done_callback` method was recently added to the distributed `Future` object which allows you to take some action after the future finishes, irrespective of whether it succeeded or not.

http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=add_done_callback#distributed.client.Future.add_done_callback

The callback function will hang if you try to directly call any of the methods `result`, `exception` or `traceback` on the passed future object.

The exception and traceback can however be accessed in the callback as follows:
`fut._exception().result()`
`fut._traceback().result()`

Trying the same pattern with the result - i.e. `fut._result().result()` raises an exception:

```
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 316, in _check_done
    raise Exception("DummyFuture does not support blocking for results")
Exception: DummyFuture does not support blocking for results
```

Without being able to access the result of the future in the callback, being able to add a callback is of limited use to me.

Am I missing something - *is* there a way to get the result of the future in the callback?

In the asyncio documentation it seems to give an example where accessing the `result` method directly is possible:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#example-future-with-run-forever

...I'm not sure how this related to tornado/distributed, but it would be *very* useful to be able to do the same.

```py
from distributed import Client


client = Client("127.0.0.1:8786")

def f(delay):
    from time import sleep
    from numpy.random import randn
    sleep(delay)
    if randn() > 1:
        1/0
    return delay

def callback(fut):
    import logging
    logger = logging.getLogger('distributed')
    if fut.status == 'finished':
        res = future._result().result()  # <-------------- Doesn't work!
        logger.info("{!r} - {!s}".format(fut, res))
    else:
        logger.info("{!r} - {!s}".format(fut, fut.status))


args = rand(10)
futs = client.map(f, args)
for fut in futs:
    fut.add_done_callback(callback)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your callback gets called within the Tornado Event loop.  If you want to get the result of the future you'll have to use the Tornado API.

Here is a minimal example:

```
In [1]: from distributed import Client
In [2]: client = Client()
In [3]: def inc(x):
   ...:     return x + 1
   ...: 
In [4]: from tornado import gen

In [5]: @gen.coroutine
   ...: def callback(future):
   ...:     result = yield future._result()
   ...:     print(result * 10)
   ...:     
In [6]: future = client.submit(inc, 1)

In [7]: future.add_done_callback(callback)

20
```

However, your question highlights that perhaps this is not the most intuitive way for users to interact with add_done_callback, so I wouldn't be surprised if we introduced a breaking change for later versions.

```
In [8]: import distributed

In [8]: distributed.__version__
Out[8]: '1.14.0'
```